# How to remove right-side workspaces panel in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, gui, workspaces, gnome-shell

The panel i'm talking about resides on the right side in gnome applications overview (just pressing super key).

In standard gnome environment if you set static workspaces to 1 in gnome-tweak-tools - the right-side workspaces panel are gone. But in Ubuntu - even
 after using tweak-tools it still appears.

Are there any method to annihilate this panel without using additional extensions ?

***UPDATE***

Some investigations showed this two functions (alt+f2 -> lg) to annihilate the panel, 
but i think there is some more elegant method...

```
Main.overview._controls._thumbnailsSlider.actor.destroy_all_children();
Main.overview._controls._thumbnailsSlider.actor.destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, however with the vanilla gnome session. If I set workspaces to "static" and numbe of workspaces to 1 in Gnome Tweaks, the workspaces indeed are gone as you indicate.

That it does not work for you may be related to the fact that you are logged in to the customized Ubuntu session.

You can install `gnome-session` to have the choice for a plain Gnome Shell session on login. That is what I run. For your information, `vanilla-gnome-desktop` is a session that takes it one step further. It mimics the former Ubuntu Gnome edition with a full default Gnome environment, including all Gnome apps such as Photos, Documents, and the Gnome browser Web.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and this alternative but i'm seeking for something more softy

Comment: Then you could try to "undo" some cannonical changes yourself to see when you come to the desired behaviour.

Comment: I think i'm not so knowledgeable to perform this task, but if you can give some direction where to dig i will appreciate...